# Dropzone.js fullscreen dropzone not working

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am trying to make a full page dropzone using Dropzone.js using the following code.
However, when dragging files onto the body of the document, they are not picked up by Dropzone and are instead opened by the web browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="dropzone-5.7.0\dropzone-5.7.0\dist\dropzone.js"></script>

        <script>

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { 
                    url: "/test/"
                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this post help me understand something new, thus this is a simple report.

By putting the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag into html, you tell the browser to run in a standard html mode.

Back to this case, since you have a body with nothing, it is zero height which cant drop file. If you remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, the body will as height as the browser client. Welcome to the `Quirks mode`.